# Visual Studio 2010 Professional crashes after opening Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

Hi i have very weird problem. My Visual Studio 2010 crashes when i try to open user controls wrote with Devexpress 12.1.8.

I tried to uninstall whole program, deleted folders, cleaned registry but crashes still happens.

When i try to open user control a windows appears "Microsoft Visual Studio has encountered a problem and needs to close." I checked in event manager and i get this error:

> ```
> Application: devenv.exe
> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: System.AggregateException
> Stack:
>    at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExceptionHolder.Finalize()
> ```

One more weird thing about this situation is that after windows popup i can see that the control has opened in background.

What can i do to stop this error?

EDIT: I checked and it seems that i can open controls writed with devexpress 13.1.6. Maybye it is a problem with devexpress? Is there a way to totally uninstall devexpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might have a problem related to a third party package or add-in, possibly not DevExpress related. Here are some things to try:

- Running Visual Studio as an administrator.
- You can try running devenv /Resetsettings (see here) in a Command Prompt which should fix any corrupted settings
- Try running devenv /ResetSkipPkgs (see here) which will avoid loading any problem packages.
- Try running devenv /Safemode (see here). If it works in safe mode then the problem is most likely a third party add-ins or package.
- You can also try Devenv.exe /log ". This will generate a file called ActivityLog.xml which might give you further clues.
- If none of those help then try repairing Visual Studio from the Control Panel.

Comment: Try this: [How to completely reset the Toolbox and enable Visual Studio to rebuild it from scratch](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18560).

Comment: Just saw your edit, it sounds like you could upgrade your 12.1.8 project to 13.1.6 using the ProjectConverter which is in the DevExpress Tools folder. (Although there should be no problem with 12.1.8 and 13.1.6 living side by side either.)

Comment: Ok reseting toolbox and rebuilding project helped. Thanks!:)